# Include exception/failed results only when a newer successfully completed result does not exist for a given job

Tags: sql-server

I wish to show rows of jobs where `status_code` equals `e` or `f` (exceptioned/failed) only in situations where there isn't a newer entry for the same `location`, and `job_name` pair where `status_code = c` (completed) since the system will retry problem jobs automatically and a newer completed job would indicate a successful recovery.

Using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` in a subquery seems like a viable start but I'm unsure how to apply the conditional logic described above.

**Example dataset:**

| location | job_name | status_code | job_execution_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Order Detection | c | 2022-12-27 15:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Order Processing | e | 2022-12-27 15:00:01.980 |
| 1 | Order Processing | c | 2022-12-27 15:00:10.777 |
| 2 | Publish Sales | f | 2022-12-27 16:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Publish Sales | e | 2022-12-27 15:00:00.000 |

**Desired output:**

| location | job_name | status_code | job_execution_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Publish Sales | f | 2022-12-27 16:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Publish Sales | e | 2022-12-27 15:00:00.000 |

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T AS  TABLE(
   location                INTEGER  NOT NULL  
  ,job_name                VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,status_code             VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,job_execution_timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @T(location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp) VALUES (1,'Order Detection','c','2022-12-27 15:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @T(location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp) VALUES (1,'Order Processing','e','2022-12-27 15:00:01.980');
INSERT INTO @T(location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp) VALUES (1,'Order Processing','c','2022-12-27 15:00:10.777');
INSERT INTO @T(location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp) VALUES (2,'Publish Sales','f','2022-12-27 16:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO @T(location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp) VALUES (3,'Publish Sales','e','2022-12-27 15:00:00.000');



SELECT location,job_name,status_code,job_execution_timestamp  
FROM @T T
WHERE status_code IN ('e','f')
AND CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @T WHERE location = T.location AND job_name=T.job_name AND job_execution_timestamp>T.job_execution_timestamp AND status_code='c') IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  = 1
```

Comment: I used CASE WHEN to Validate  the Results Returned by the Query so thought it would be  okay to use CASE WHEN. Initially I thought of using IF NOT EXISTS but during Result check was not sure about the results.